# Setting up a matrix of time and space for a function

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, differential-equations, calculus

I'm writing a program in matlab to observe how a function evolves in time. I'd like to set up a matrix that fills its first row with the initial function, and progressively fills more rows based off of a time derivative (that's dependent on the spatial derivative). The function is arbitrary, the program just needs to 'evolve' it. This is what I have so far:

```
xleft = -10;
xright = 10;
xsampling = 1000;
tmax = 1000;
tsampling = 1000;
dt = tmax/tsampling;
x = linspace(xleft,xright,xsampling);
t = linspace(0,tmax,tsampling);
funset = [exp(-(x.^2)/100);cos(x)];   %Test functions.
funsetvel = zeros(size(funset));      %The functions velocities.
spacetimevalue1 = zeros(length(x), length(t));
spacetimevalue2 = zeros(length(x), length(t));
% Loop that fills the first functions spacetime matrix.
for j=1:length(t)
        funsetvel(1,j) = diff(funset(1,:),x,2);
        spacetimevalue1(:,j) = funsetvel(1,j)*dt + funset(1,j);
end
```

This outputs the error, `Difference order N must be a positive integer scalar.` I'm unsure what this means. I'm fairly new to Matlab. I will exchange the Euler-method for another algorithm once I can actually get some output along the proper expectation. Aside from the error associated with taking the spatial derivative, do you all have any suggestions on how to evaluate this sort of process? Thank you.

Comment: The keyword for what you're doing might be "Euler-method". Arrays are nice, your friend is right. Also, what does `diff(funset(1,j),x,2)` return for you near the end...?

Comment: I will eventually implement a symplectic algorithm to enhance precision rather than stick with the Euler-method. As for the array computation, I'm having a hard time finding material over how to program such. Maybe I'm not using the proper terminology. Lastly, matlab will not fulfill this code and I believe it is because the diff(~~~) function evaluates analytics, whereas I've given it an array of values representing the function. I believe the fix to this would be to have an algorithm that numerically computes the spatial derivative, but am unsure of how to do this as well.

Comment: `diff()` will exactly compute a numerical finite difference. The problem is that you're not passing an array to it, but a single element: `funset(1,j)`. This is why I asked what `diff()` returned for you.

Comment: I believe I understand now. Running the code produced, `Difference order N must be a positive integer scalar.` From what you say, I should scrap the for-loop involving the position, yes? I should rather evaluate the entire rows each step. So just the for-loop spanning time, or is there a more concise method?

Comment: It depends on whether the time steps are independent. Definitely implement it first with a time loop, using array operations in space. Then you'll be able to assess whether time steps can be treated at the same time. The main question is probably "does the behaviour in one time step depend on previous time steps?". If the answer is "no", you'll be able to vectorize it easily. Otherwise it's probably difficult/impossible.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge this will very much by past-dependent. This said, it appears the best approach is to move through time and fill the `spacetimevalue1` matrix right? I have the following loop for the process, `for j=1:length(t)
        funsetvel(1,j) = diff(funset(1,:),x,2);
        spacetimevalue1(:,j) = funsetvel(1,j)*dt + funset(1,j);
end` However, I still recieve the same error, `Difference order N must be a positive integer scalar.` I'm still having a hard time wrapping my mind around these process' and their associated syntax. Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: @Andras: Thanks, I'll clean things up now.

Comment: Take a close look at the [documentation of `diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html), and the error message. `diff()` will only compute the simple difference of elements, you have to divide it by `diff(x)` to get an actual derivative. `x` cannot be passed to `diff()`. Also: you'll get an assignment error if you fix this, since you're trying to assign an array to a scalar. If you fix that, you'll have a dimension mismatch error, since `diff(v)` has fewer elements than `v`. Take your time to study the documentation, and perhaps the "getting started" guide for matlab:)

Comment: @Andras: Okay, I will squeeze these in this afternoon and report back probably tomorrow. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: Good luck, don't mention it.

Comment: It seems you are discretizing the heat equation `u_t=c*u_xx`. This is no Hamiltonian system, so it is doubtful that symplectic methods will work. Higher order Runge-Kutta or multi-step methods are however possible. Try out the standard Crank-Nicolson method. What are the boundary conditions?

Comment: I forgot about the relation between hamiltonian and symplectic algorithms. I will do rungekutta. The conditions are open. Ideally I'd like to observe all space but am primarily concerned with some adjustable center. My velocity is subject to change as well. I just need to get the framework laid so to speak then adjust for other initial functions and velocities.